# a way to get log2(x) value correctly in g++,

Tags: g++

on window c++, it was available to use log2 function by
#include
or
#include<math.h>

But on g++
log2 function seems to give me wrong values.

How can I use log2 function in g++?

Comment: You can always do `log (x) / log (2)`

Comment: What kind of wrong result? Please post your code3, expected result, and actual result.